# Make a tool with HTML to generate Excel files or HTML email

Tags: html

I want to make a html website and use it locally, as a 'tool' to generate an Excel table or just an HTML for email.

I have to put some items in a table, add the price, quantity, etc and sum all the products value..and sometimes to add a discount. Right now I'm doing this manually and its not very efficient since I don't have a database or something and I have to write all the data manually every time.

So my question is: it is possible to make a html website to do this stuff? And also to create a database to store the products info. And also it can be done without php? Since I only need the browser to do all the job and then save/export the generated file.

I only know some html and CSS, so that's why I'm asking for a html way to accomplish this..but if you have a better idea, i'm open to listen.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you add a sheet in your Excel file with input boxes and a macro? If all you want as output is the Excel file I wouldn't suggest doing all the effort to create a website + database. You will at least some kind of javascript/php since plain HTML will only to tell the browser how to render your webpage.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you will have to use Javascript or PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is adding information to your excel file, I wouldn't suggest doing all the effort to create a website + database. Besides, you will at least some kind of javascript/php since plain HTML will only to tell the browser how to render your webpage.

Other possibilities from my side:

Option 1: Why don't you add a sheet in your Excel file with input boxes and a macro? If all you want is some kind of interface to add items to your Excel file, I wouldn't suggest doing all the effort to set up a website + database. If your Excel file will grow to big, I would suggest option 2.

Option 2: You could also think about creating an Access database with some kind of UI to add items to it. Depending on the goal this would be a prefered solution over a website + database.

Comment: Aha..Thanks. I forgot to mention that I would prefer to can access it from other devices like Android smartphone. But I think for now your ideas are the best:) One more question, what kind of database is used to store info(like in my case) for html websites? Maybe store the data in XML files?

Comment: For websites the most common is a MySQL database and not too hard to set up. If your file is pretty static, XML can be used, but I would prefer mySQL when you have a lot of records to maintain and have to edit your data frequently.